# How can I complete the implementation of parser for this mini prolog in haskell?

Tags: parsing, haskell, prolog

```
module Parser where

import Text.Parsec
import Lexer
import AST

type Parser = Parsec [(SourcePos, Token)] ()

tokenP :: (Token -> Maybe a) -> Parser a
tokenP test = token show fst (test . snd)

symbol :: String -> Parser ()
symbol c = tokenP (\t -> case t of
  TSym s -> if s == c then Just () else Nothing
  _ -> Nothing)

functorP :: Parser (String, [Term]) -- functor and relation have the same parser
functorP = error "not yet implemented"

termP :: Parser Term
termP = do
    name <- tokenP (\t -> case t of
                        (TName s) -> Just (Atom s)
                        (TVar s) -> Just (Var s)
                        _ -> Nothing)
    case name of -- parser consumes name which can be of atom or functor
      (Atom a) -> (fmap (Func a) . between (symbol "(") (symbol ")")
                 . flip sepBy1 (symbol ",") $ termP) <|> return name
      _ -> return name

{- parse a relation or cut in body of clause -}
relP :: Parser Rel
relP = (symbol "!" *> return Cut) 
       <|> relHeadP

{- parse a relation in head of clause -}
relHeadP :: Parser Rel
relHeadP = fmap (uncurry Rel) functorP

ruleP :: Parser Rule
ruleP = error "not yet implemented"

programP :: Parser Program
programP = fmap Program $ many ruleP

parseProgram :: String -> Either ParseError Program
parseProgram source = do
  tokens  <- parse (tokensL   <* eof) "" source
  parse (programP <* eof) "" tokens

parseRel :: String -> Either ParseError Rel
parseRel source = do
  tokens  <- parse (tokensL   <* eof) "" source
  parse (relHeadP <* (symbol ".") <* eof) "" tokens
```

I am not very sure what to do for funtorP and ruleP. can someone explain it with codes? thanks

here is the link for the zip file which includes other package: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mW7zJdi0UbLPLO9t94A9vbOIgmspUMAE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I don't know Haskell yet but since Haskell is a functional language like OCaml and you are trying to parse Prolog this might help. [miniProlog](https://github.com/andrejbauer/plzoo/tree/master/src/miniprolog). (It is a different implementation, the name just happens to be a coincidence) If this answers your question I can post it as an answer. Also just ignore the others that don't don't agree with your question. You can't succeed if you quit. :) IIRC it does not handle `cut` but you can add that latter after you get the basics of Prolog done.

Comment: When parsing Prolog IIRC, don't parse `!` (cut) as part of Prolog. Parse it as an operator and then during the semantics phase process it as needed.

Comment: Any chance you got your code in some public CSV? If not, It's way more convenient for you and whoever decides to have a look.